# How to remap number keys and number key special characters in VIM

Tags: vim, remap

I am trying to remap the * operator in VIM.  I have tried `nnoremap <*>` and `nnoremap <S-8>` to no avail.  I haven't been able to find any instructions on how to properly do this.  How can I remap my *, or any number keys/number key special characters?

Since many of you will no doubt wonder why anyone would want to do this, it's so I can make my * operator behave like normal, except not advance automatically to the next occurrence of the word under cursor (see under section [Highlight Matches Without Moving](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_all_search_pattern_matches)).

EDIT:

The complete command I'm working with is this:

`nnoremap <*> :let @/='\<<C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR>\>'<CR>:set hls<CR>`

Where `*` remaps the functionality of `*` or `<shift + 8>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting rid of the `<` and `>` works for me.

```
nnoremap * :let @/='\<<C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR>\>'<CR>:set hls<CR>
```

Comment: @Freedom_Ben Check out `:h key-notation`. Everything not listed there needs to be used without surrounding `<…>`. Also note that vim uses byte queue to represent typed keys and is never receiving anything like `Shift` + `8`: never anything with modifiers. `<C-…>` keys are one byte control characters resting between 0x01 and 0x1F in ASCII table, `<A-…>` are `<Esc>…` and things like `<F1>` are internal escape sequences starting with 0x80 byte (in terminal they are first received as something like `<Esc>[11~`, but then transformed). `<S-a>` is additionally `A`. You can always use this directly.

Comment: @ZyX, thanks for the awesome explanation!  That clarifies things greatly.  If you want to post it as an additional answer, I'll vote it up.  I think it would be really helpful to people visiting this question in the future as well.

Answer (score -1):

Try `nnoremap <F7> <*>`. It will remap the * with F7

Comment: I tried your suggestion several ways and it didn't seem to work.  Can you provide a more complete example?  I've added my entire command to the question.

Comment: This will remap `<F7>` with three symbols: `<`, `*` and `>`.